# How could the domain in different areas resolve to a different IP address?

Tags: network, dns, domain

When I nslookup the domain in area1, it get `103.61.39.86`

```
[root@localhost ~]# nslookup demo.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   demo.com
Address:    103.61.39.86
```

but when I nslookup the domain in area2, it get `47.94.236.96`

```
[root@localhost ~]# nslookup demo.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   demo.com
Address:    103.61.39.86
```

---

if using CDN, in general, the nslookup should resolve to a CNAME, so can judge the `www.demo.com` case is not using CDN?

```
[root@localhost ~]# nslookup otafsg-cost-az.demo.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   otafsg-cost-az.demo.com
Address: 184.87.193.87
Name:   otafsg-cost-az.demo.com
Address: 184.87.193.77
Name:   otafsg-cost-az.demo.com
Address: 2600:140b:a00:c::b81b:b945
Name:   otafsg-cost-az.demo.com
Address: 2600:140b:a00:c::b81b:b957
> Server:       8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   otafsg-cost-az.demo.com
Address: 184.87.193.77
Name:   otafsg-cost-az.demo.com
Address: 184.87.193.87
Name:   otafsg-cost-az.demo.com
Address: 2600:140b:a00:c::b81b:b957
Name:   otafsg-cost-az.demo.com
Address: 2600:140b:a00:c::b81b:b945
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Is there a practical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Also, what is area1 and area2, which domain are you actually trying to resolve (demo.com has IP addresses in a different range) and can you make sure your output matches the text? Please also add the version of macOS you are running.

Comment: See also: [EDNS Client Subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDNS_Client_Subnet) (allowing to return different IPs depending on the client's geolocation) and [Round-Robin DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS).